# Lost Session variable when use ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection()

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, configurationmanager

I have a website and have multi domain point to this.
In my website code when use access to web, I use ConfigurationManager to change Connect string base every domain. Code bellow

```
     Session["Key"] = "KeyID"; 
     var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
     string fullConnect = "New String Connnect";
     connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings["Name"].ConnectionString
        = fullConnect;
     configuration.Save();
     ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

But I lost every Session variable initialization before Connect string change (like Session["Key"]).
How can i do that but kip my Session variable?.

Answer (score 1):

If you update connection string in Web.config file then session will surely destroy. To prevent this, set multiple connection strings in Web.config file and whichever connection string you want, you can manage it in .cs file.

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="String1"
         connectionString="CONNECTION STRING1"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="String2"
         connectionString="CONNECTION STRING2"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

You can get connection in code using "ForEach" loop.

```
foreach (ConnectionStringSettings cstring in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
{
    //use cstring.name
}
```

Comment: Tks your answer  but my project use EF so i only chage contain of connect string.

Comment: My orther question. can i rediection url  example "www.abc.com/abc" to web site 'www.abc.com"

Comment: Yes, you can redirect URL using Routing.